# Cyclos Docker SSL Impelementation for tomcat

Tags: ssl, tomcat, lets-encrypt

I have configured tomcat inside docker container as follows

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                   maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
            <SSLHostConfig>
                <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="my.jks"
                             type="RSA" />
            </SSLHostConfig>
        </Connector>

        <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
                   maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
            <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
            <SSLHostConfig>
                    <Certificate certificateKeyFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
                            certificateFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem"
                            certificateChainFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem"
                             type="RSA" />
```

Restarted the docker container but its not accessible via https

where my.jks is stored inside tomcat/conf directory.

I configure docker container as follows:

```
docker run -d \
    --name=nameofcontainer \
    -p 80:8080 \
    -p 443:8443 \
    --net=cyclos-net \
    --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
    -e DB_HOST=cyclos-db \
    -e DB_NAME=cyclos \
    -e DB_USER=cyclos \
    -e DB_PASSWORD=cyclos \
    image-id
```

But website is not accessible via https or port 8443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [SSL/TLS Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File):

> To define a Java (JSSE) connector, regardless of whether the APR library is loaded or not, use **ONE** of the following:
>
> ```
> <!-- Define a HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443, JSSE NIO implementation -->
> <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" port="8443" .../>
>
> <!-- Define a HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443, JSSE BIO implementation -->
> <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" port="8443" .../>
> ```

Why do you use both connectors together on the same port?

You should use one of them only. Or configure them on the different ports.